# how can i display MS team type bannner when there is no internet connection in electron or javascript?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to display some kind of banner to user  when the device is offline or the electron application cannot  connect to internet .Is theree any way I can do this .I can check if the application is online or not as of now I am just logging it in console I want to show the same in ui something like below .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```html
<div id="offline-banner">
  No internet. Reconnect to keep the conversarion going
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#offline-banner {
  zIndex: 10;
  position: 'absolute';
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Then just show the element when there is no connection and hide it when there is connection